# Flutter Scan QR code without show the camera

Tags: flutter, qr-code

I'm working on a Flutter project that scans QR code but I don't need to render the camera image on the screen.

I've tried to use these packages:

https://pub.dev/packages/qrscan,
https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner

but none of them scans the QR code without render the camera image at the screen.

Is there any other way I could do this on background?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`qr_code_scanner`](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) plugin and wrap it into an `Opacity` `Widget`:

```
Opacity(
    opacity: 0,
    child: 
      QRView(),
),
```

However, make sure to carefully consider the end-user experience before implementing such feature.